# Wordpress search not able to find text in url

Tags: search

I am publishing posts with lists of colleges. The college name is a url which points to inner pages. For some reasons, wordpress search is not able to find the text.
For eg if the post had University of florida as a hyperlink and I search for Florida in wordpres search box, no results are returned.
If I do view source, I can see the text.
I am using wordpress 3.8

for eg this is the one of the post
http://studyn.us/2014/10/12/masters-embedded-system-engineering/

It has **North Carolina** as a url.
I am searching **North Carolina** and this post should have returned but that is not happening.

Appreciate the help

Comment: My experience has been that most search engines (including WP) find the "most relevant" hits for your search. Searching for North Carolina yields some hits, so the page you reference might simply be considered "not relevant enough" to display. Note that searching for "masters in embedded" (no quotes) DOES work, so the page **is** being indexed.

Comment: @barrycarter thanks for explanation. I understand the relevance but if there is no other page, then the single page should be displayed.

Comment: I agree, but when I search for North Carolina, many pages show up. When I search for "masters in embedded" (no quotes), only one page comes up. Are you seeing different results?